# R JAGS: invalid parent value in node (combining dcat and dnorm)

Tags: r, jags, rjags

I am a newbie when it comes to using Jags and Rjags.

```
modelString = "
model {
for (i in 1:N){
    y[i] ~ dt(mu,tau,nu)

}

tau <-   nuless2/(sig^2) 
nuless2 <- nu / nuless
nuless <- (nu-2)
sig ~ dnorm(0.02045457,10000000)
mu ~ dnorm(0.0013942308,4000000000)
nu ~ dcat(pi[])
pi <- c(0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
}"
writeLines(modelString,con="model.txt")
line_data = list("y"=ret,"N"=length(ret))

init_value = list("mu"=0.003)
model <- jags.model("model.txt", data=line_data, n.chains=2)
```

I have been struggling to get this code to work and I have no idea while it is giving me the error.

> Error: Error in node nuless2
>   Invalid parent values

I experienced around to see what the problem lies and read most of discussion but I couldnt see any reason.

It would be great if someone can tell me where my stupid mistake is.

Also, I am quite new to JAGS and would like to know how the flow of the system works. For example, while I define `y ~ dt()`, I also supply data for `y`. By doing so, am I telling the system this is what the data is and all the parameter in `dt()` need to be "verified" using this data? It would be great to have a deeper understanding of such system.

Comment: update: I put a static value into nu and the code run. dcat() might be the problem

Comment: It looks like JAGS is initializing the node nuless2 without understanding the constraints imposed by the parents.  This problem can probably be fixed by manually specifying the inits for each node in a way that ensures consistency.

Comment: @JacobSocolar I am not sure that I understand your idea entirely. I got my code to work by feeding in a fixed vector of nu/(nu-2) then use the dcat to make the nu vector into stochastic node. Check my code below:  
`modelString = "
model {
    for (i in 1:N){
        
        
        y[i] ~ dt(mu,tau,nu[ind])
        
    }
    tau <-   nu[ind]/(sig^2) 
    
    sig ~ dnorm(0.02045457,10000000)
    mu ~ dnorm(0.0013942308,4000000000)
    ind ~ dcat(pi)
    pi <- rep(1,7)
}
"
nu = c(3,2,5/3,6/4,7/5,8/6,9/7)`